# Using OpenCL backend for dnn module of openCV 4.6.0

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

I'm trying to run openCV's dnn module in c++
I'm getting an error i've seen a number of time around but never found a proper answer so far

> OpenCV(ocl4dnn): consider to specify kernel configuration cache directory
> via OPENCV_OCL4DNN_CONFIG_PATH parameter.
> OpenCL program build log: dnn/dummy
> Status -11: CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE
> -cl-no-subgroup-ifp
> Error in processing command line: Don't understand command line argument "-cl-no-subgroup-ifp"!

I'm on windows, using openCV 4.6.0 that i compiled myself with the OpenCL flag turned on.
Code runs fine when using the CPU target but throws the previous mentioned block when switching from DNN_TARGET_CPU to DNN_TARGET_OPENCL. It doesn't crash but from what i can see it doesn't use the GPU and runs even slower than with the CPU option.

I was able to create and use a python version of the same code without any hitch (opencv-python 4.6.0 / same model / usecase) and it used my GPU just fine so it must be some configuration that is wrong on the c++ side.

May anyone have an idea ? Thanks

Comment: Looks like this: [https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14187](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14187)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it indeed appears to be the same problem but sadly it wasn't answered in that thread, something definitely isn't working here as the GPU isn't used at all.

Comment: I do agree that closing was a bit unsatisfying. I think the answer was it will still use the GPU if your version of opemcl does not support the flags used but you probably won't get full performance.

Comment: So it might be something to do with the openCL version ? i might need to reorient the question to "how to get full performance of openCL with that module in c++" then ?

Answer (score 1):

So after some testing on different hardware it appears that the OpenCL implementation only works with integrated graphic chips. Tested on two different machine and it worked with their integrated GPUs, tested on other hardware (Nvidia and AMD graphic cards) and it doesn't work. I assume we have to wait for better support to come around, especially for AMD cards where the CUDA backend isn't an option.